# Is it possible to deploy a devcontainer as a private ACI?

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-code

Ive been attempting to deploy and connect remotely to an azure container instance running in a private network in azure (with a VPN set up).

I have no problem accessing the container using the aci docker context or directly using the exposed services (I have http and vnc set up on the container).

However, the end goal is to use the container as a remote visual-studio-code development container  - with a git repo mounted on the container.

Having trouble figuring out how to do this... From reading the docs it almost seems as if setting up ssh would be the only way to do this but then it seems like I have to set up my own docker host instead of creating the docker as an ACI.

Has anyone done this before?  Is it possible?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/88